# VB6 Program - Runtime Error 429 ActiveX component can't create object (EXCEL)

Tags: excel, vb6, activex

I have a VB6 executable application and I'm trying to make it work in Windows10. Everything works except from one of it's functions which is to collect data from an opened Excel Workbook. Whenever I try to do that I get a "Runtime Error 429 - ActiveX component cannot create object". I have installed Microsoft Office 2013 and Microsoft Excel 2000. The error is the same for both versions of Excel Opened. Can you help me ?

Comment: Are you running 32 bit Office 2013? Can you show the relevant bit of code?

Comment: Sry for not responding sooner.  Firstly, I don't have access to the code. I just know that it was written in VB6 (If it's a problem in the code I obviously cannot fix it, but maybe there's a problem with the references/dlls). Secondly, my Office 2013 is 64bit but as I've said the error is the same with both versions of Microsoft Office (2013 and 2000). Thanks in Advance!

Comment: VB6 addins will not work with a 64 bit version of Office. The error is very likely caused by your Office 2013 installation. Removing Office 2013 and installing the 32 bit version of Office 2013 is likely to solve the issue.

Comment: Ty. I will do that. However, if this is the issue why am I encountering the same error when using Microsoft Excell 2000 which is 32 bit?

Comment: I've installed Office 2013 32 bit on a fresh Windows 10 machine and I installed the program as well. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Hmm, the only thing I have left up my sleave is to advise you to remove one of the two Office versions, but I cannot guarantee that'll work. SO perhaps that isn't worth the hassle.